# Probability distribution and elementary events from sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question on the set of elementary events that can be used to determine probability of a distribution.  I present some definitions to start and the question follows.

The probability mass function is defined:

Let $X$ be a function of random variable, $r_k \in \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega$ is the sample space, $P$ is the probability function $\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal F = \mathcal P(\Omega)$.  $P_X$ is the PMF.

$P(X = r_k) = P_X(r_k) = P(\{s \in \Omega: X(s) = r_k\})$

The geometric distribution, which expects independent trials, is used for an example.

$P_X(k) = (1 - p)^{k-1} p$

It appears from this definition the PMF can be calculated either using the probability function $P$ or the defined equation for the geometric distribution above.

Questions: what would $\Omega$ be for this distribution.  I'm suspecting $\Omega = \{0,1\} \times \{0, 1\} \times ... \times \{0,1\}$?  The trials may be different lengths so that is confusion my understanding.  How does one correctly assign $P(A)$, where $p \ne \lnot p$?  Can $n$ trails event be represented in a single space space $\Omega$?

Approaching this from a more set theoretic standpoint with regards to the events seems to complicate things.  Appreciate your guidance.